# adding a custom time class to <body> in theme twenty sixteen

Tags: customization, body-class

I'm moving on from the child of a (no-longer serviced) 2009 theme to a child of **twenty sixteen** - I previously had a code in my functions that generated the week number as a body class - e.g `w32` (for this week for example.)

I'm using the following code in my old theme but of course it no longer functions in **twenty sixteen**. Are there any tips to implement it there? The following is in the `functions.php` of my child folder:

```
// Adds 'week' and parent-page id body-class

add_filter( 'hybrid_body_class', 'my_body_class' );

function my_body_class( $class ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $time = time() + ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * 3600 );
    $class .= ' w' . gmdate( 'W', $time );

    if ( is_page() && $wp_query->post->post_parent )
        $class .= ' parent-' . $wp_query->post->post_parent;

    return $class;
}
```

As I'm no longer using the hybrid theme, I've tried changing `hybrid_body_class` to `body_class` and multiple other variants - to no avail or with errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Twentysixteen's](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/) [`header`](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentysixteen/1.2/header.php#L24) and [`functions.php`](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentysixteen/1.2/functions.php#L290) appear to support the [`body_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/body_class) filter.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'my_body_classes');

function my_body_classes($classes) {

        global $wp_query;

        $time = time() + ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * 3600 );
        $classes[] = 'w' . gmdate( 'W', $time );

        if ( is_page() && $wp_query->post->post_parent ){
             $classes[] = 'parent-' . $wp_query->post->post_parent;
        }

        return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks jgraup - wordpress-stack is my new reference - as an oldie I was still using stack exchange ;-)

Comment: Great. Glad it worked out for you.